# Can I mod Vivaldi with CSS/JS to trigger @media (prefers-color-scheme:dark)?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries, darkmode, vivaldi

I'm using Vivaldi on Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria (Xfce). As I understand it, even though I have a dark theme, my browser can't detect this, so web pages display by default on light mode. I'd like to have web pages display in dark mode using the `@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark)` query, not some extension or chromium flag that forces web pages into non-native dark mode. Is this possible using Vivaldi's CSS or JS modding capabilities?

I really have no clue where to start here. I'm just a hobbyist looking to modify my own viewing experience, and the other questions I've seen about overriding `prefers-color-scheme` prefs are from web developers looking to add a toggle or something on their websites.

#### Edit 2023/08/03

Here's an idea: in DevTools, I can use the Rendering tool and select "Enable automatic dark mode" to do what I'm looking for, which is setting `prefers-color-scheme` to dark. I can also use the "Emulate CSS media feature prefers-color-scheme" to do effectively the same thing. Is there a way to automate either of these settings to load on every web page? Of course, I'm still open to other solutions, especially those just involve native Vivaldi tinkering without DevTools.

Comment: It looks like you'd have to use something like tampermonkey (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo). That will allow you to change the setting you're looking at, rather than a "dark mode" extension

Comment: @TrevorNewhook from what I've seen online I don't know if you can edit the default media query value from JS. Is this true? Also, couldn't I do the same thing with a Vivaldi JS mod?

Comment: Does launching Vivaldi from the command line with `--force-dark-mode` work for you? It does not work for me, but some sources claim it might also work on some Linux distros.

Comment: @t.niese unfortunately this doesn't work for me